# You may wanna set down the Milk Duds for this one

Tags: american-english

I know what "milk duds" are, but can't figure out what this phrase means.
It is pronounced in Zombieland - Double Tap by Jesse Eisenberg's character when he describes "Zombie kill of the year."
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you’re not squeamish around blood and gore...

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen the sequel, but in the original, this character often speaks directly to the audience. In this case, they are advising the audience that something shocking or scary or gory or in some way unsavory is about to happen or be said. Milk Duds are a candy that is often eaten by people at the movies, so advising people to "set down the Milk Duds" suggests that whoever is watching the movie might not want to be eating for whatever happens next, as people typically don't like to eat during scenes of intense blood and gore.

Comment: Thanks, that fits very well!